# python: divide a dataframe into the same intervals as another dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, intervals

I divided the following dataframe into 4 intervals according to the 'ages' column.
Let's say that I want another dataframe to have the same exact intervals, is there a quick way to do so?
In other words, the following lines

```
df1['age_groups'] = pd.cut(df1.ages,4)
print(df1['age_groups'])
```

divides the dataframe into the following intervals

```
(1.944, 16.0]    5
(16.0, 30.0]     3
(30.0, 44.0]     2
(44.0, 58.0]     2
```

but if I have a different dataframe with slightly different numbers in a column with the same name, the same code will produce different intervals.
How do I make sure I can subdivide other dataframes into the same intervals?

```
ages=[35.000000,
       2.000000,
      27.000000,
      14.000000,
      4.000000,
     58.000000,
     20.000000,
     39.000000,
     14.000000,
     55.000000,
      2.000000,
     29.699118]
values=[1,0,1,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,1]
df1=pd.DataFrame()
df1['ages']=ages
df1['values']=values
#print(df1)

df1['age_groups'] = pd.cut(df1.ages,4)
```

Comment: The `bins` parameter in `pandas.cut` can take break points or interval index https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.cut.html

Answer (score 2):

1. Save the bins from the first DataFrame using the `retbins` keyword
2. Use it as the `bins` argument in for the second DataFrame:

```
df1['age_groups'], bins = pd.cut(df1["ages"], 4, retbins=True)
df2['age_groups'] = pd.cut(df2["ages"], bins=bins)
```

###### Working example:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

np.random.seed(100)
df1 = pd.DataFrame({"ages": np.random.randint(10, 80, 20)})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({"ages": np.random.randint(10, 80, 20)})

df1['age_groups'], bins = pd.cut(df1["ages"], 4, retbins=True)
df2['age_groups'] = pd.cut(df2["ages"], bins=bins)

>>> df1.head()

    ages     age_groups
0   18  (11.935, 28.25]
1   34    (28.25, 44.5]
2   77    (60.75, 77.0]
3   58    (44.5, 60.75]
4   20  (11.935, 28.25]

>>> df2.head()

    ages     age_groups
0   11              NaN
1   23  (11.935, 28.25]
2   14  (11.935, 28.25]
3   69    (60.75, 77.0]
4   77    (60.75, 77.0]
```

Comment: your code generates the following error: TypeError: min() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

Comment: @johnjohns - No idea what you're doing wrong, but I added a complete working example. There is definitely no error thrown from my code.

Comment: your code works, Thanks. I can see that there is a 'nan' entry and that is because there must be a number in df2 not falling in any of the df1 intervals. How do you find out which numbers are those ? I tried with a for loop but I get this error: TypeError: 'pandas._libs.interval.Interval' object is not iterable

Comment: After you get the above, you can do `df2[df2["age_groups"].isnull()]` to see all the `NaN` values. However, that is a *new* question. If you have any more follow-up questions, please make a new post as the current question has been answered.